# Get date from DatePicker in another xml file on Android

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I want to get date (Day,Month,Year) from DatePicker in another xml file. But app errors NullPointerException without use theInflatedView. If I use theInflatedView, doesn't get date. How I get date from DatePicker in another xml file?

```
   public void customAlertDialog(){

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(HesapActivity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dateset);
        dialog.setTitle("Date");
        theInflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dateset, null);
        final DatePicker dpFirst = (DatePicker) theInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
        final str;
        dpFirst.init(dpFirst.getYear(), dpFirst.getMonth(), dpFirst.getDayOfMonth(),new OnDateChangedListener() {

             @Override
             public void onDateChanged(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
             str=(arg3+ "."+ (arg2+1) + "."+arg1);
             }
             } );

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.setDPBt);
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {       
                textFirst.setText(str);//textFirst is MainActivity variable.
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();


  }
```

in onCreate()

```
 customAlertDialog();
```

dont setText date when button in AlertDialog clicked

------Update--------

I solved problem In below

```
final DatePicker dpFirst = (DatePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);//I changed theInflatedView to dialog
```

Comment: Hi there please give the stacktrace, I used your code with my DatePicker and the date is changing.

Comment: I dont use 'Log.i' -- I 'm using tv.setText on click button.

Comment: And, dateset.xml in AlertDialog. I use custom AlertDialog

Comment: I need to see a stacktrace or some code, are you using two different fragment with xml layouts or two different activities?

Comment: ok, i will update my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change below:

```
public void customAlertDialog(){

final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(HesapActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dateset);
    dialog.setTitle("Date");
    theInflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dateset, null);
    final DatePicker dpFirst = (DatePicker) theInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
    final str;
    dpFirst.init(dpFirst.getYear(), dpFirst.getMonth(), dpFirst.getDayOfMonth(),new OnDateChangedListener() {

         @Override
         public void onDateChanged(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
         str=(arg3+ "."+ (arg2+1) + "."+arg1);
         }
         } );

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.setDPBt);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {       
            textFirst.setText(str);//textFirst is MainActivity variable.
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();


  }
```

To

```
public void customAlertDialog(){

final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(HesapActivity.this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dateset);
    dialog.setTitle("Date");
    theInflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dateset, null);
    final DatePicker dpFirst = (DatePicker) theInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
    final str;
    dpFirst.init(dpFirst.getYear(), dpFirst.getMonth(), dpFirst.getDayOfMonth(),new OnDateChangedListener() {

         @Override
         public void onDateChanged(DatePicker arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
         textFirst.setText(arg3+ "."+ (arg2+1) + "."+arg1);
         }
         } );

    Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.setDPBt);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {       
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();


  }
```

Comment: There are always simpler ways to get something done, I also don't see a problem with the following code as It works with my DatePicker and TextView 100%

Comment: R.id.datePicker1(dpFirst) in dateset.xml-----R.id.textView1(textFirst) in main_activity.xml

Comment: i solved problem ---- I changed final DatePicker dpFirst = (DatePicker) theInflatedView.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);---to-- final DatePicker dpFirst = (DatePicker) dialog.findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);